# Migrating Ubuntu from a MBR disk to a GPT disk (non-UEFI)

Tags: uefi, bios, lvm, mbr, gpt

The question is: how to Migrate Ubuntu installed on a LVM Logical Volume with a separate boot partition from a MBR disk to a GPT disk on non-(U)EFI hardware without data loss to enable the usage of partitions larger than 2TB?

Comment: I am not one for migrating or imaging, but believe it is a lot easier to just reinstall to the new drive and use rsync to copy /home. You will have to export list of installed apps & reinstall and may have some system configuration in /etc. If a server you may have server type software for web, apache, database and that is another whole level of issues.

Comment: @oldfred I also have an Apache server running there for ownCloud as well as a Samba share so I figured it would be better to move everything instead of searching for the config files I edited. It took a lot of effort to find out how to do that but with a tested step-by-step guide its rather easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have struggled through finding an answer and wrote a [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Migrate%20Ubuntu%20installed%20on%20a%20LVM%20Logical%20Volume%20from%20a%20MBR%20disk%20to%20a%20GPT%20disk%20on%20non-%28U%29EFI%20hardware%20without%20data%20loss#preview) with a step-by-step solution. Feel free to use it.